# Varied results on Linq list select

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple method to calculate the growth between items in a list.  Something strange is happening where the first and second dump will show different results for the first item.

Good 1000/1300/0.3.
Bad 1700/1300/-0.23.

I'm really stumped, can anyone help?

```
void Main()
{
    List<TestItem> items = new()
    {
        new() { EndDate = new DateTime(2020, 3, 31), CloseValue = 1300M },
        new() { EndDate = new DateTime(2020, 6, 30), CloseValue = 1600M },
        new() { EndDate = new DateTime(2020, 7, 31), CloseValue = 1700M },
    };

    var openValue = 1000M;

    var completeItems =
            items.Select(x =>
            {
                var item = new TestItem
                {
                    EndDate = x.EndDate,
                    OpenValue = openValue,
                    CloseValue = x.CloseValue,
                };

                openValue = item.CloseValue;
                return item;
            });
            
    completeItems.Dump();
    completeItems.Dump();
}

class TestItem
{
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenValue { get; set; }
    public decimal CloseValue { get; set; }
    public decimal Growth => (OpenValue == 0) ? 0 : (CloseValue - OpenValue) / OpenValue;
}
```

Comment: Note that using side effects like this can be very confusing for the readers. If you need to do things like this I would suggest a regular loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing strange here - `completeItems` is a Linq query, when you call `.Dump()` on it, the query **is executed** and you modify the  `openValue` variable three times, eventually assigning it `1700M` (in third iteration).

When you call `.Dump()` another time, the query is executed again, but now `openValue` has a "starting" value of `1700M` not `1000M`. Hence the result of `1700M` and negative growth in the second dump.

Answer (score 2):

That's the reason for your confusion:

```
var openValue = 1000M;    

openValue = item.CloseValue;
```

In the first iteration, your openValue is 1000M. At the end of your first iteration, you set the openValue to the closeValue of the last item in your list, which is 1700M. Starting then a new iteration will give you an initial openValue of 1700M, which is causing the differing values for the first item. Reset the openValue before you run your function and you will be fine.

```
completeItems.Dump();
openValue = 1000M;
completeItems.Dump();
```